# US visa appointment wait time inconsistency

Tags: usa, visa, canada

I am trying to make an appointment for an American F1 visa interview in Vancouver, Canada. I am a Third Country National resident in the US with Australian citizenship.

The wait time on [this](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/general/wait-times.html/) website is listed as 2 days. However, when I go to make an appointment on [this](https://usvisa-info.com) website the earliest listed appointment is 125 days away. What is the reason for this inconsistency?

Answer (score 3):

I called the US visa information service number 703-439-2319 listed [here](https://usvisa-info.com/en-ca/selfservice/us_service_options). They were able to allocate an appointment consistent with the 2 day wait time indicated on the `travel.state.gov` website.

Interestingly, as I was speaking to the call center I refreshed the listing of available appointments and many more suddenly became available. This may be an indication of a bug in the appointment allocation website.

Comment: I had the same issue this week when I was trying to book an appointment. I called the service number and they mentioned that the official appointment wait times are for Canadian residents only. Since I am not a Canadian resident, an appointment is available to me only after 4 months instead of the official appointment wait time which is 14 days.